# Django undirected unique-together

Tags: python, django, model, unique-constraint

I want to model pair-wise relations between all members of a set.

```
class Match(models.Model):

    foo_a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo_a')
    foo_b = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo_b')

    relation_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('ingredient_a', 'ingredient_b')
```

When I add a pair A-B, it successfully prevents me from adding A-B again, but does not prevent me from adding B-A.

I tried following, but to no avail.

```
unique_together = (('ingredient_a', 'ingredient_b'), ('ingredient_b', 'ingredient_a'))
```

**Edit:**
I need the relationship_value to be unique for every pair of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overridden the save method of the object to save 2 pairs every time. If the user wants to add a pair A-B, a record B-A with the same parameters is automatically added.

Note: *This solution affects the querying speed. For my project, it is not an issue, but it needs to be considered.*

> ```
> def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     if not Match.objects.filter(foo_a=self.foo_a, foo_b=self.foo_b).exists():
>         super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
>     if not Match.objects.filter(foo_a=self.foo_b, foo_b=self.foo_a).exists():
>         Match.objects.create(foo_a=self.foo_b, foo_b=self.foo_a, bar=self.bar)
> ```

**EDIT:** Update and remove methods need to be overridden too of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a model like what you defined, its not just a ForeignKey, its called a ManyToMany Relation.

In the django docs, it is explicitly defined that unique together constraint cannot be included for a ManyToMany Relation.

From the docs,

> A ManyToManyField cannot be included in unique_together. (It’s not clear what that would even mean!) If you need to validate uniqueness related to a ManyToManyField, try using a signal or an explicit through model.

**EDIT**

After lot of search and some trial and errors and finally I think I have found a solution for your scenario. Yes, as you said, the present schema is not as trivial as we all think. In this context, Many to many relation is not the discussion we need to forward. The solution is, (or what I think the solution is) **model clean method**:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    foo_a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo_a')
    foo_b = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo_b')

    def clean(self):
        a_to_b = Foo.objects.filter(foo_a = self.foo_a, foo_b = self.foo_b)
        b_to_a = Foo.objects.filter(foo_a = self.foo_b, foo_b = self.foo_a) 

        if a_to_b.exists() or b_to_a.exists():
            raise ValidationError({'Exception':'Error_Message')})
```

For more details about model clean method, refer the [docs here...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

Comment: I want the relationship_value to be unique for every given two items. That means that you would need to limit the ManyToMany relationship to only 1 item at a time, which is not trivial as far as I know.

Comment: Your edit does prevent inconsistency. Thank you for the input. I solved it by creating redundant pairs A-B, B-A. The table will not be used for production queries, but only to construct a confusion matrix for future use, so performance is not an issue.

I still wonder which of the two approaches would be better if performance had to be taken into account. Your approach has the advantage that you don't need to override update and remove methods.